# CSS opacity delay with no fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change an elements opacity of 0 to 1 after 6 seconds and I do not want a fade.

I have this code:

```
.rs-background-video-layer iframe {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s linear 1 normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
from{
   opacity: 0;
}
to{
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

But this has a fade. I just want the opacity to change from 0 to 1 after 6 seconds. Can I do this with CSS or do I have to do with it jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at animation-delay? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755425/css-delay-transition